# Generating a CSV from Excel VBA with cleardown function

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, excel-tables, listobject

I've got a VBA script in Excel to extract a list of values from Table1 Column 1 (Literally just a list of Laboratory numbers and can be any number of rows, usually no more than 30) and drop it into a CSV on a shared drive where NiceLabel will pick it up and process it.
The data is then cleared from the original CSV so the next person can use it. (currently it deletes rows 2-30)

However some users still manage to break the code and end up printing a 33MB csv file (they somehow manage to generate all 1million rows and the script then tries to attach them to a csv.
Is there a simpler way of doing this which removes the risk of user error (and subsequent clogging of the printers)

```
Sub printlist()
'
' printlist Macro
'

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="\\SVWDLIMSPRINT1\OnDemand\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Rows("2:30").Select
Selection.Delete
    Range("Table1[[Lab Number]:[Lab Number]]").Select
    Selection.ClearContents


'
End Sub
```

The above works 99.9% of the time but that 0.1% generating excessively large files causes serious disruption.
Alternatively is there a method in NiceLabel using VBScript to reject larger files.

Comment: How about finding the last row that is populated and instead of copying the table to the file that becomes the CSV just assign the values of that range.
If the users apply formatting at a column level you can end up with all rows being included

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values From an Excel Table

- If you use the table range, you don't care what the user does outside of it.
- If a stubborn user adds a million rows to the table, you're trouble remains.

```vb
Sub ExportList()
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("List")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("Table1")
    ' Not sure what you want to do with the column.
    'Dim slc As ListColumn: Set slc = slo.ListColumns("Lab Number")
    
    ' Check if the table is empty.
    If slo.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The table is empty.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slo.Range ' maybe 'slc.Range'?
    ' If you don't want to copy the headers,
    ' replace `.Range` with `.DataBodyRange`.
    
    ' Reference the destination range (same size as the source range).
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    Dim drg As Range:
    Set drg = dws.Range("A1").Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    ' Copy values from source to destination.
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value

    ' Save and close the destination workbook.
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        dwb.SaveAs Filename:="\\SVWDLIMSPRINT1\OnDemand\" _
            & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".csv", _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it just got saved

    ' Empty the (source) table.

    With slo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .DataBodyRange.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End With
    
    ' Save the (modified) source workbook.
    
    'swb.Save SaveChanges:=True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "List exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```